# Which is the best way of correct filter for HTML editor in PHP?

Tags: php, editor, filter, javascript

I'm using TinyMCE editor in my site. I want to learn way of correct filter for my input when i'm inserting to DB. Which filters are need to use? For example i get this input to DB this way;

```
$example = $_POST['example'];

<textarea name="example"></textarea>
```

I'm not using htmlscepialchars(); because i need the html tags.

"Sorry for my poor English."

Comment: The question is not clear. Where will you put the contents of `$example`. What do you want not to allow?

Comment: @Artefacto i want to allow html tags but i want to obstruct the unwanted sql queries and the others of unwanted codes.

Answer (score 2):

HTMLPurifier.

Download it here: http://htmlpurifier.org/

Include it:

```
include 'path/to/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';
```

Use it:

```
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('Core', 'Encoding', 'UTF-8');
$config->set('XHTML', 'Doctype', 'XHTML 1.0 Strict');
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
$clean_html = $purifier->purify( $dirty_html );
```

And sleep well knowing there are no XSS attacks in HTML cleaned like this.

People suggesting mysql_real_escape_string() probably didn't get your question (or i didn't), you were asking how to filter HTML markup from a WYSIWYG editor so it can be safely stored in a database.

mysql_real_escape_string() is relevant as a protection against SQL injection but prepared statements (google "PDO") are better for that.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to save html to your database, and need some way to encode it?

You could do the following before saving to the db:

```
urlencode($_POST['example']);
```

And when you retrieve, you can urldecode($data);

Comment: Is there a reason I got down-voted? The answer I gave is a viable solution - so, whoever down-voted better come forward and explain why they feel it's not...